# How to set the selected radio-button in a XMLUI radiogroup?

Tags: flash, dialog, default, radio-group, jsfl

In some examples on the web (http://ajarproductions.com/blog/2011/03/03/creating-flash-extensions-pt-4-ui/) there is "fake" demonstration that claims that this works:

```
<!-- ... somewhere inside the XMLUI dialog file ... -->
<radiogroup id="myFileExtension">
  <radio value=".json" label=".json" selected="true" />
  <radio value=".txt" label=".txt" />
  <radio value=".xml" label=".xml" />
</radiogroup>
```

But... `selected="true"` doesn't do jack!

The **radiogroup** always selects the first item regardless of which has the **selected** attribute.

Is there any XMLUI experts out there that knows another parameter that is actually supported to assign the default Radio button?

I am basically trying to open a dynamic XMLUI dialog and the JSFL script must be able to set the default selection based on the last settings used (which I store in a JSON document elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way out be to create an init() method onCreationComplete.. then simply set the radio button to selected via actionscript instead of explicity within the mxml code.

```
<mx:RadioButtonGroup id="group"/>
        <mx:RadioButton groupName="group" id="button1" value="false"
                        label="first button"/>
        <mx:RadioButton groupName="group" id="button2" value="true"
                        label="second button"/>


public function onInit() {
     button2.selected = true;
}
```

Comment: This is not MXML, it is XMLUI, not Flex, there's a big difference.